# Проблема с добавление в БАЗУ

Tags: jquery, php

Подскажите в чем проблема почему не добавляет а базу данных запись.
Вот код:

```
 $('#shareButton').livequery("click", function () { 
       var textarea_content = $('textarea#wall').val(); 
       if (textarea_content != '') { 
           var sitetitle = $('label.title').html(); (if there's any )
           if (sitetitle == null) {
               sitetitle = ' ';
           }

           var siteurl = $('label.url').html(); 
           if (siteurl == null) {
               siteurl = ' '; displayed on page
           }
           var sitedesc = $('label.desc').html(); 
           if (sitedesc == null) { 
               sitedesc = ' '; 
           }
           var current_image_id = $('input#current_img').val(); 
           if (current_image_id != '') { 
               var current_image_url = $("img#" + current_image_id).attr("src");
               if (current_image_url != '') { 
                   var image_html = '<div class="img_attachment"> <img class="external_pic" width="90" height="67"  src="' + current_image_url + '">'; 
               } else {
                   var image_html = ''; 
               }
           } else {
               var image_html = ''; 
           }

           var wall_post = '<li> <img src="image/avatar.jpg" class="avatar">    <div class="status">     <h2><a href="#" target="_blank">Hyder Abbass</a></h2>  <p class="message">' + textarea_content + '</p> ' + image_html + '<div class="data"><p class="name"><a href="' + siteurl + '" target="_blank">' + sitetitle + '</a></p><p class="caption">' + siteurl + '</p><p class="description">' + sitedesc + '</p></div></div> </div><p class="likes">5 hours ago ·            100 Likes </p></li>';
     var message_wall = $('#message_wall').attr('value');

           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "insert.php",
               data: "message_wall=" + wall_post,
               success: function () {
                   $('ul#posts').prepend(wall_post);

               }
           });
```

А вот insert.php

```
    <?php
session_start()

include_once("bd.php");

if(isset($_POST["message_wall"]) && strlen($_POST["message_wall"])>0) 
{

    $message_wall = $_POST["message_wall"];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO records(content) VALUES('$message_wall')");

?>
```

Подскажите в чем проблема ?Что не так в обработчике ?Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Выведете "INSERT INTO records(content) VALUES('$message_wall')", затем попробуйте вставить его в MySQL.

Если все отработает нормально и запись добавится - значит как-то подключаетесь не так в include_once("bd.php"); Там уже по ошибкам смотрите.

Либо, если не добавится - по ошибкам определите что не так в запросе

Comment: Уберите <pre>(if there's any )</pre>

Answer (score 1):

На стороне клиента тип запроса get (`type: "GET",`), а сервер думает, что запрос должен быть post (`if(isset($_POST["message_wall"]) && strlen($_POST["message_wall"])>0)`);

Приведите к одному типу.

Comment: На стороне сервера тогда будет выглядит для GET запроса вот так вот 

      (if(isset($_GET["message_wall"]) &&      strlen($_GET["message_wall"])>0));

да ?

Comment: да, либо на клиенте `type: "POST",`

Comment: а сам код обработчика дальнейший правильный ?

Comment: вроде одной закрывающей фигурной скобки не хватает.

Comment: Проблема остается актуальной,добавление не происходит.

Comment: Это код, скопированный один в один? тогда он действительно не будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Азы отладки.
 1. Проверьте работает ли вообще php скрипт с правильным вводом. Эмулируйте правильные данные.
 2. Проверьте что отдает js серверу

Вы даже не выяснили на какой стороне ошибка, вывалили простыню кода и хотите узнать ответ.